# jQuery - Compare two values and show or hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/6k6ehnn2/

Hello,
I need to make , if the value is greater than or equal to 1000.00 function display the div `.boleto`, but does not display ... Where am I going wrong in comparing the two strings?

```
<span class="valor">R$ 200,00</span>
<div class="boleto">pagamento em boleto</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
    var valorMinimoBoleto = '1000,00';
    var valorTratado = $(".valor").html().replace('R$ ','');
    var valorBoleto = valorTratado;
    if ( valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto ) {           
        console.log('valor exibe boleto');
    } else {
        $('.boleto').hide();
        console.log('valor não exibe boleto');
    };    
});
```

Comment: In Javascript decimal point is dot, not comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because both the `valorMinimoBoleto` and `valorBoleto` are Strings, so your if condition does not work there.

So, first convert them into number using `number()` method like this

```js
$(function(){
    var valorMinimoBoleto = 100000;
    var valorTratado = $(".valor").html().replace('R$ ','');
    var valorBoleto = Number(valorTratado);
     if ( valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto ) { 
      console.log('valor exibe boleto');
     } else {
      $('.boleto').hide();
      console.log('valor não exibe boleto');
     };    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="valor">R$ 200,00</span>
<div class="boleto">pagamento em boleto</div>
```

As LinkinTED 22 said, we can also use `toggle()` function instead of `if..else`, like this :

```js
$(function(){
    var valorMinimoBoleto = 100000;
    var valorTratado = $(".valor").html().replace('R$ ','');
    var valorBoleto = Number(valorTratado);
     $('.boleto').toggle( valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="valor">R$ 200,00</span>
<div class="boleto">pagamento em boleto</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Instead of the last if else, you can you use [`toggle(statement)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display), like this: `$('.boleto').toggle( valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto );`

Comment: @LinkinTED Thanks for sharing it man. Learned a new technique from you

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two strings here `if ( valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto )`

You need to first parse them before they can be compared numerically.

E.g:

```
   var valorMinimoBoleto = '1000,00';
    var valorTratado = $(".valor").html().replace('R$ ','');
    var valorBoleto = valorTratado;

   var parsedValorMinimoBoleto = parseFloat(valorMinimoBoleto);
   var parsedValorBoleto = parseFloat(valorBoleto);


    if (parsedValorBoleto >= parsedValorMinimoBoleto) {           
        console.log('valor exibe boleto');
    } else {
        $('.boleto').hide();
        console.log('valor não exibe boleto');
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Guys. All the solutions are great.

Answer (score 0):

We want it to be a number as opposed to a string, so no need for the `'`'s also I think you have to use `.` rather than `,` for the decimal point

Here is the code working, and below that is the code again but with a larger number.

```js
$(function() {
  var valorMinimoBoleto = 1000.00;
  var valorTratado = $(".valor").html().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.');
  var valorBoleto = valorTratado;
  if (valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto) {
    console.log('valor exibe boleto');
  } else {
    $('.boleto').hide();
    console.log('valor não exibe boleto');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="valor">R$ 200,00</span>
<div class="boleto">pagamento em boleto</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  var valorMinimoBoleto = 1000.00;
  var valorTratado = $(".valor").html().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.');
  var valorBoleto = valorTratado;
  if (valorBoleto >= valorMinimoBoleto) {
    console.log('valor exibe boleto');
  } else {
    $('.boleto').hide();
    console.log('valor não exibe boleto');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="valor">R$ 1200,00</span>
<div class="boleto">pagamento em boleto</div>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.